# PHP how to loop over nested JSON Object?

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
1. Extracted from my laravel controller:
```

```php
        ..
        ..
        $data = json_decode($response, true);
        return $data;
        ..
        ..
        return view('homepage')->with('homeExclusives', $homeExclusives);
```

2. Here is a sample of the returned data, just a short version, since the returned feed is very large, but this will give you an idea of the way it's structured.

```
     array(4) {
       ["success"]=> bool(true) 
       ["status"]=> int(200) 
       ["bundle"]=> array(2) {
           [0]=> array(631) {
               ["StreetDirPrefix"]=> string(2) "SW" 
               ["DistanceToStreetComments"]=> NULL
           }

           [1]=> array(631) { 
               ["StreetDirPrefix"]=> string(2) "NE" 
               ["DistanceToStreetComments"]=> NULL
              }
      }
```

3. I need to extract "StreetDirPrefix" value from [0] and [1], but I always get an error. Can someone help?

Comment: Show what you've tried, please. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what error you are getting my solution would be something like this:

```
<?php
if (is_array($data) && is_array($data["bundle"]) ) {
    foreach ($data["bundle"] as $tmpKey => $tmpVal) {
        if (isset($tmpVal["StreetDirPrefix"])) {
            echo $tmpKey." => ".$tmpVal["StreetDirPrefix"]."\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I always like to validate arrays, so if your `$data` variable or the `$data["bundle"]` subsection are not arrays then you will not get anything. Not even an error.

I have a working example here:
[https://www.seeque-secure.dk/demo.php?id=PHP+how+to+loop+over+nested+JSON+Object](https://www.seeque-secure.dk/demo.php?id=PHP%20how%20to%20loop%20over%20nested%20JSON%20Object)

EDIT:

(if i understand you correct)
When you have validated your array all you have to do is repeat the inner validation like this:

```
<?php
if (is_array($data) && is_array($data["bundle"]) ) {
    foreach ($data["bundle"] as $tmpKey => $tmpVal) {
        if (isset($tmpVal["StreetDirPrefix"])) {
            echo $tmpKey." => ".$tmpVal["StreetDirPrefix"]."\n";
        }
        if (isset($tmpVal["UnparsedAddress"])) {
            echo $tmpVal["UnparsedAddress"]."\n";
        }
        if (isset($tmpVal["SalePrice"])) {
            echo $tmpVal["SalePrice"]."\n";
        }

        //...... ect.....

    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Excellent example, one more question, how can I make it work if I want to extract multiple values and display them, I'm trying to create a featured properties row, example "StreetDirPrefix", "UnparsedAddress", "SalePrice" & "mainImage" and also not show the "0 => ".

Comment: I actually analized the you example and was able to remove the => and loop over other values, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For the data in your example you might use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and specify `StreetDirPrefix` as the column key.

```
$res = array_column($array["bundle"], "StreetDirPrefix");
print_r($res);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/aPfi4)

Comment: Thank you, how can I use a loop to list all of the "StreetDirPrefix"?

Comment: Excellent example, one more question, how can I make it work if I want to extract multiple values and display them, I'm trying to create a featured properties row, example "StreetDirPrefix", "UnparsedAddress", "SalePrice" & "mainImage" and also not show the "0 => ".

Comment: That is a different question and a very broad one as well. That depends how the data is structured in the array. In that case my advice would be to ask a new question adding the code and specifying the data and the desired result.